# BibTeX error persists after pdflatex-->bibtex-->pdflatex-->pdflatex compilation

Tags: bibtex

I realize this sounds like a duplicate question, but as far as I can tell, none of the answers address my problem. In both TexMaker 4.5 and TexWorks 2.9, I tried using BibTeX to compile a simple document, of the form:

```
% Untitled.tex 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{BibTeX in action}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
text \cite{ahu61} 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibl}

\end{document}
```

with a .bib file containing

```
@article{ahu61,
   author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
   title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
   journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
   volume={8},
   year = 1961,
   pages = {175-191}
 }
```

In TexMaker, I compile this using pdflatex-->bibtex-->pdflatex-->pdflatex. In TexWorks, I compile this using "pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex" several times. This successfully creates an `.aux` file, but it produces an empty `.bbl` file. The logs contain the phrase "LaTeX Warning: Citation `ahu61' on page __ undefined on input."

Does anyone know how I can get this working? I've been searching for 2 hours, and most answers don't seem helpful for my situation.

**Edit -- the output of my .blg file:**

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: untitled.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file bibl.bib
---line 5 of file untitled.aux
 : \bibdata{bibl
 :              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file untitled.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ahu61"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ab94"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Note that my actual .bib file contains two sources, but I didn't think they were both relevant to post.

Comment: is the .bib file name `bilbl.bib`?

Comment: Yes, the .bib file is bibl.bib and is in the same folder

Comment: What exactly does the bibtex run say?

Comment: Can't post everything due to char. limit. The relevant part seems to be:

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `ahu61' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.

(C:\Users\William\Desktop\untitled.bbl

LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

) [1

{C:/Users/William/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\William\Desktop\untitled.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:

Comment: @William You'll need to cut down your input to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which shows the issue but does fit on the site (it really should be doable). Without that it will be hard for us to help.

Comment: @Joseph I'm sorry, but the entire content of my example is included in my post. I was asked for the bibtex run -- I was unsure how to interpret this so I posted the relevant part of the .log file (which I abbreviated as much as possible). 

If daleif was asking for the relevant bibl file, I included the entire text of it in my original post. 

I therefore don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @William Do you have a `.blg` file? If so, can you edit it in.

Comment: @Joseph No .blg files. All I have, aside from the .bib, .tex, and .pdf files are an .aux file, an empty .bbl file, a .txt, a synctex file and a performance monitor file.

Comment: @William The 'performance monitor file' is the `.blg`: it just happens to have the same extension as used by the Windows program.

Comment: @Joseph Updated in the original post.

Comment: @William As suggested earlier, there is no file called `bibl.bib` in the folder. Can you turn on showing file extensions in Explorer and check the _full_ filenames in the folder.

Comment: @Joseph: You seem to be right -- apparently I was having 2 problems. The first was that the file for my MWE was named bibl.bib.tex. The second seems to be related to the TexWorks editor, and remains unresolved. When I compile using TexWorks, no blg file is generated -- presumably, the compiler is not working as anticipated. However, the document compiles using TexMaker, and that's enough for me. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a misnamed bib-file (filename.bib.tex).